# How do I implement a racing clock that shows elapsed time?

Tags: software-engineering, game-mechanics

I'm wanting to make a old school timer like the picture below. How would I go about doing this in VD? I have tried it doing it with code bellow. The problem with this is that it starts with just seconds only adds the minutes section when you reach 1 minute.

[image]

```
Dim StartTime As DateTime
Dim PlayTime As TimeSpan

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    StartTime = Now()
    End Sub

  Private Sub tmrCountUp_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrCountUp.Tick

    PlayTime = Now() - StartTime

    lblTime.Text = PlayTime.Hours & PlayTime.Minutes & PlayTime.Seconds

    lblTime.Text = lblTime.Text + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: You have tried, and what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Old school? What do "new school" timers look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can format using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx
or use string formatting (string.padleft I think)